# How to center vertically a text beside a switch?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a text in "toggle-label" class center vertically with the "switch", but I'm failed
Here is the code that i use

```css
.toggle-label {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 54px;
  height: 28px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider-round {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider-round:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.switch input:checked+.slider-round {
  background-color: #e53f71;
}

.switch input:focus+.slider-round {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #e53f71;
}

.switch input:checked+.slider-round:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

```html
<span class="toggle-label">BGM</span>
<label class="switch" style="margin-right: 20px;">
     <input type="checkbox" id="bgm" checked>
     <span class="slider-round"></span>
</label>
<span class="toggle-label">SFX</span>
     <label class="switch">
     <input type="checkbox" id="sfx" checked>
<span class="slider-round"></span>
</label>
```

I have try to set the top padding of the toggle-label, but it still don't work
Please help me to make the toggle-label center vertically with the switch

Comment: Wrap each pair inside a wrapper (e.g. `<div>`), then set `display: flex; align-items: center;` to that. Also, you might want to add the text inside `<label>` for semantical reasons. This is a common task, so there must be at least one duplicate target somewhere; I can't find one just yet, but consider this a close vote.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

*vertical-align: middle;*

to *.toggle-label* and *.switch*.

That should make them nice an even with each other.

Comment: That don't work